# INVALID_ARGUMENT: expected compatible input types, but input 1: What does this TF error mean and how do I resolve this?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I have been working on a neural network and want to train it through tensorflow's FastAPI and when I trigger training, this error shows up; that I cannot comprehend-

```
2023-01-05 19:17:57.881722: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/forward_type_inference.cc:231] Type inference failed. This indicates an invalid graph that escaped type checking. Error message: INVALID_ARGUMENT: expected compatible input types, but input 1:
type_id: TFT_OPTIONAL
args {
  type_id: TFT_PRODUCT
  args {
    type_id: TFT_TENSOR
    args {
      type_id: TFT_BOOL
    }
  }
}
 is neither a subtype nor a supertype of the combined inputs preceding it:
type_id: TFT_OPTIONAL
args {
  type_id: TFT_PRODUCT
  args {
    type_id: TFT_TENSOR
    args {
      type_id: TFT_LEGACY_VARIANT
    }
  }
}

        while inferring type of node 'binary_crossentropy/cond/output/_10'
2023-01-05 19:18:16.532189: I tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc:390] Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while): 361 of 5000
2023-01-05 19:18:26.305368: I tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc:390] Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while): 635 of 5000
2023-01-05 19:18:36.170004: I tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc:390] Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while): 1017 of 5000
2023-01-05 19:18:46.177664: I tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc:390] Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while): 1263 of 5000
2023-01-05 19:18:56.154804: I tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc:390] Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while): 1559 of 5000
2023-01-05 19:19:06.208777: I tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc:390] Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while): 1949 of 5000
2023-01-05 19:19:16.177522: I tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc:390] Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while): 2147 of 5000
2023-01-05 19:19:26.192117: I tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc:390] Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while): 2282 of 5000
2023-01-05 19:19:36.637720: I tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc:390] Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while): 2448 of 5000
2023-01-05 19:19:46.256679: I tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc:390] Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while): 2621 of 5000
2023-01-05 19:19:56.203889: I tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc:390] Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while): 2829 of 5000
2023-01-05 19:20:06.300115: I tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc:390] Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while): 3083 of 5000
2023-01-05 19:20:16.191704: I tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc:390] Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while): 3338 of 5000
2023-01-05 19:20:26.192851: I tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc:390] Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while): 3669 of 5000
2023-01-05 19:20:36.212527: I tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc:390] Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while): 4049 of 5000
2023-01-05 19:20:46.401018: I tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc:390] Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while): 4398 of 5000
2023-01-05 19:20:56.168909: I tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc:390] Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while): 4596 of 5000
2023-01-05 19:21:06.164738: I tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc:390] Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while): 4821 of 5000
2023-01-05 19:21:07.181289: I tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc:415] Shuffle buffer filled.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Radhe Krishna\OneDrive\Documents\MarkATT\main.py", line 527, in <module>
    training_history = model.fit(train,epochs=10, validation_data = val)
  File "C:\Users\Radhe Krishna\OneDrive\Documents\MarkATT\MarkATT\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\Radhe Krishna\OneDrive\Documents\MarkATT\MarkATT\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 54, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'gradient_tape/sub_2/BroadcastGradientArgs' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Radhe Krishna\OneDrive\Documents\MarkATT\main.py", line 527, in <module>
      training_history = model.fit(train,epochs=10, validation_data = val)
    File "C:\Users\Radhe Krishna\OneDrive\Documents\MarkATT\MarkATT\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\Radhe Krishna\OneDrive\Documents\MarkATT\MarkATT\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1409, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    File "C:\Users\Radhe Krishna\OneDrive\Documents\MarkATT\MarkATT\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1051, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\Users\Radhe Krishna\OneDrive\Documents\MarkATT\MarkATT\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1040, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "C:\Users\Radhe Krishna\OneDrive\Documents\MarkATT\MarkATT\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1030, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "C:\Users\Radhe Krishna\OneDrive\Documents\MarkATT\main.py", line 500, in train_step
      grad = tape.gradient(total_loss, self.model.trainable_variables)
Node: 'gradient_tape/sub_2/BroadcastGradientArgs'
Incompatible shapes: [2,4] vs. [8]
         [[{{node gradient_tape/sub_2/BroadcastGradientArgs}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_22025]
```

For your reference, this is the training class that I intent to use-

```
class FaceTracker(Model):
    # Making the initialization function to instantiate our model fro training
    def __init__(self,facetracker,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.model = facetracker
    # Making the compile method to compile all the losses and optimizers needed to train the model
    def compile(self, optimizer,classloss,localization_loss,**kwargs):
        super().compile(**kwargs)
        self.classloss = class_loss
        self.localization_loss = regress_loss
        self.optimizer = optimizer
    # Defining the training step where the backprop shall be applied to our data
    def train_step(self,batch,**kwargs):

        X,y = batch
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            classes,coords = self.model(X,training=True)
            batch_classloss = self.classloss(y[0],classes)
            batch_localloss = self.localization_loss(y[1],coords)

            total_loss = batch_localloss+0.5*batch_classloss
            grad = tape.gradient(total_loss, self.model.trainable_variables)
            optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grad,self.model.trainable_variables))
            return{
                "total_loss":total_loss,
                "class_loss":batch_classloss,
                "localization_loss":batch_localloss
            }
        # Definging the testing step for the model, which is similar to the train_step but without backprop
        def test_step(self,batch,**kwargs):
            X,y = batch
            classes,coords = self.model(X,training=True)
            batch_classloss = self.classloss(y[0],classes)
            batch_localloss = self.localization_loss(tf.cast(y[1],tf.float32),coords)
            total_loss = batch_localloss+0.5%batch_classloss
            return{
                "total_loss":total_loss,
                "classloss":batch_classloss,
                "localization_loss":batch_localloss
            }
        #Defining a lambda function that should act as a call function.Lambda is used so as to prevent us from having to subclass the method to make a child class
        lambda self,X,**kwargs: self.model(X,**kwargs)
```

It would be a great help if someone could give me insights on how do I resolve this issue.
For more clarity, I also raised a related query earlier that you could visit and dive deeper into
[My query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74761871/how-to-deal-with-incompatible-shapes-while-trying-to-fit-a-model-in-tensorflow-k)

Thanks in advance!!

Trying to initiate training of a Neural Network, but getting this eerror that I cannot understand myself**your text**

Comment: What are your `x` and `y` look like? what is the shape of your logit? At which place (Line Number explicitly) the error came?

Comment: Thanks for replying@MohammadAhmed
My X and Y are actually a set of training images and their associated labels. 
X- Images, y-labels
Which I ave modified in tensorflow to finally bring them down as numpyiterator object.
Here is the snippet that might help-
-
train = tf.data.Dataset.zip((train_images,train_labels))
train = train.shuffle(5000)
train = train.batch(8)
train = train.prefetch(4)
-
Then I am using it as a NumPy iterator object:
-
    X,y = train.as_numpy_iterator().next()
    classes, coords = facetracker.predict(X)
-

Comment: The error arises at this line-
training_history = model.fit(train,epochs=10, validation_data = val)